# I Want Pop Up Window To Appear If No Validation Errors

Tags: javascript, validation, function, popup, project

I have a button known as "Prepare Questions". Now when I click on this button, this button does two things, using the validaton() function it validates the form so that if there is an error in the form (empty textbox and radio button not selected) then it displays the suitable error messages on the page. But also the button uses the "openSessionPopup" function so that it opens up a pop up window which states the word "Session".

The problem is that when I click on the button it does both functions, so it displays validation errors if there is some and also opens up the pop up window.

What I want to do is that the pop up window should only be displayed after there are no validation errors. But I can't seem to get this to work, does anyone else know how to do this.

Below is my code:

```
 <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
            <title>Create a Session</title>
            <script type="text/javascript">

     function validation() {

                    var btnRadioO = document.getElementsByName("sessionNo");               
                    var isbtnRadioChecked = false;;

                    var dateTextO = document.getElementById("datepicker");
                    var timeTextO = document.getElementById("timepicker");


                    var errMsgO = document.getElementById("radioAlert");

                    var errDateTimeMsgO = document.getElementById("dateTimeAlert");
                    var errDateMsgO = document.getElementById("dateAlert");
                    var errTimeMsgO = document.getElementById("timeAlert");


                    for(i=0; i < btnRadioO.length; i++){
                        if(btnRadioO[i].checked){
                            isbtnRadioChecked = true;
                        }
                    }

                    if(!isbtnRadioChecked) {
                       errMsgO.innerHTML = "Please Select the Number of Sessions you Require";
                    } else {
                        errMsgO.innerHTML = "";
                    }                                

         if (dateTextO.value == ''){
                    errDateMsgO.innerHTML = "Please Select a Date";
                }else{
                    errDateMsgO.innerHTML = ""; 
                }

         if (timeTextO.value == ''){
                    errTimeMsgO.innerHTML = "Please Select a Time";
                }else{
                    errTimeMsgO.innerHTML = ""; 
                }
    }

                       function openSessionPopup (session) {
     window.open(session,
     'window',
     'width=500,height=500,scrollbars=yes,status=no');
     }

    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <form action="create_session.php" method="post">

     <table>
              <tr>
              <th>Number of Sessions :</th>
              <td class="sessionNo"><input type="radio" name="sessionNo" value="1" />1</td>
              <td class="sessionNo"><input type="radio" name="sessionNo" value="2" />2</td>
              <td class="sessionNo"><input type="radio" name="sessionNo" value="3" />3</td>
              <td class="sessionNo"><input type="radio" name="sessionNo" value="4" />4</td>
              <td class="sessionNo"><input type="radio" name="sessionNo" value="5" />5</td>
              </tr>
              </table>
              <div id="radioAlert"></div>
     <p><input type="text" id="datepicker" >
                <br/><span id="dateAlert"></span></p>
                <p><input type="text" id="timepicker" >
                <br/><span id="dateTimeAlert"></span><span id="timeAlert"></span></p>

<p><input class="questionBtn" type="button" value="Prepare Questions" name="prequestion" onClick="validation();openSessionPopup(this.href); return false"  /></p>
    </form>

    </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should move your event handlers out of your html markup.

Next you should bind an event handler to that click event.

After that you should modify your validation method to return true or false to denote if it passed validation or not.

Last you should use that validation result in a conditional wrapping your showpopup method invocation.

Something like

```
function myClickHandler(){
     if(validation()){
        showSessionPopup();
     }
}
```

for your handler and this how how you would bind it

```
document.getElementsByName("prequestion")[0].addEventListener('click', myClickHandler);
```

Finally you would modify your validation method like so

```
function validation() {
    var result = true;
                var btnRadioO = document.getElementsByName("sessionNo");               
                var isbtnRadioChecked = false;;

                var dateTextO = document.getElementById("datepicker");
                var timeTextO = document.getElementById("timepicker");


                var errMsgO = document.getElementById("radioAlert");

                var errDateTimeMsgO = document.getElementById("dateTimeAlert");
                var errDateMsgO = document.getElementById("dateAlert");
                var errTimeMsgO = document.getElementById("timeAlert");


                for(i=0; i < btnRadioO.length; i++){
                    if(btnRadioO[i].checked){
                        isbtnRadioChecked = true;
                    }
                }

                if(!isbtnRadioChecked) {
                   errMsgO.innerHTML = "Please Select the Number of Sessions you Require";
                   result = false;
                } else {
                    errMsgO.innerHTML = "";
                }                                

     if (dateTextO.value == ''){
                result = false;
                errDateMsgO.innerHTML = "Please Select a Date";
            }else{
                errDateMsgO.innerHTML = ""; 
            }

     if (timeTextO.value == ''){
                errTimeMsgO.innerHTML = "Please Select a Time";
                result = false;
            }else{
                errTimeMsgO.innerHTML = ""; 
            }

     return result;
}
```

This will make your validation() method return false if you have errors.

Comment: I have two questions, first what do you mean by moving event handlers outside html markup and second question is how do you set a  function to equal true or false, in other words how do you set so if all validations are clear it equals false else true?

Comment: @MalcolmPickup I've edited my answer to help you out more with your solution. Ive added how to bind events in javascript and how to modify your validation method. Enjoy!